# Yajra dataTable filtering . Not working

Tags: php, yajra-datatable

Im trying to search on Datatable , but getting this error:

> Exception Message:↵↵SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'AS fullname like ?) or LOWER(`drivers`.`street_no`) LIKE ?
>   or LOWER(`drivers`.`s' at line 1

and this what the resultant query

```
'select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `drivers` where (LOWER(`drivers`.`id`) LIKE %fuj% or LOWER(`drivers`.`licence_no`) LIKE %fuj% or (CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS fullname like %fuj%) or LOWER(`drivers`.`street_no`) LIKE %fuj% or LOWER(`drivers`.`status`) LIKE %fuj%)) count_row_table'.
```

Any help would be really appriciated ..

Thanks